# how to search a question mark in the visual filter in power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I am looking the way to search a question mark (?) in a string in a Filter inside Power BI?
Looking for the single question mark is like a wild card. The point here is that I need to see all string containing questions marks.

[image: Filters]

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about the filters, but when it comes to the search function, prefixing the question mark (?) with a tilde (~) usually does the trick. You can simply search for `~?`.

Hope this helps.

*Note: I tried searching for `?` in the slicer filter and it seems to be working fine. Which filter are you trying to use?*

Comment: Thanks for your response, the filter I use is the Standard Filter inside Power BI. Anyway seems tha it works... don't know how it works, because if I search '?????' I enter '~?~?~?~?~?' but it seems looking something else than just '?????'. Maybe '~' means another wild card?

Comment: '~' is just about asking Power BI to consider the '?' not as a wildcard. The '~?~?~?~?~?' seems to work fine within the search function. It may be easier to figure out what's happening if you share examples of what you are seeing.